# Download, unzip and run a file from GitHub

Tags: command-line, wget, mono, unzip

I'm absolutely new to Linux and I would like to know how could I download through the command line a .zip file from GitHub releases e.g. https://github.com/username/repo/releases/download/ver/file.zip

Then unzip the zipped folder to a new directory, and finally run it.

```
wget https://github.com/username/repo/releases/download/ver/file.zip  // Downloading the file
sudo apt install unzip // Installing unzip
unzip file.zip // Unzipping the zipped file
sudo apt install mono-runtime // Installing mono-runtime (because the program is .NET)
cd Extracted // Going to the Extracted folder
mono File.exe // Running the file
```

Is it correct? Or are there better ways to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.ubuntupit.com/how-to-zip-and-unzip-files-on-ubuntu-linux-an-ultimate-guide/

Comment: This is a Ubuntu Q&A site, not a Linux site. What OS/product/release?  (`apt` doesn't work on Ubuntu Core systems at a minimum)